# Updating Angular Element Ref broken when using Angular Material Buttons

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-directive

I'm trying to update the disabled property on a button through a directive. But having `mat-raised-button` attribute on the button won't let the button be set to disabled.  Here's my HTML.

```
<button  mat-raised-button color="primary" *hasPermission="PERMISSION_TYPES.Admin; justDisable: true" >
    DISABLE USER
</button>
```

Then in my structural directive i'm disabling the button.

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[hasPermission]', // tslint:disable-line
})
export class HasPermissionDirective implements OnInit {
    @Input() public hasPermission;
    @Input() public hasPermissionJustDisable = false;
    constructor(
        private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef,
        private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
        private permissionService: PermissionValidationService,
        private elementRef: ElementRef<any>) {
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.checkPermission();
    }

    private checkPermission() {
        this.permissionService.hasValidPermission(this.hasPermission)
            .then((hasPermission) => {
                if (!hasPermission && !this.hasPermissionJustDisable) {
                    this.viewContainer.clear();
                    return;
                }
                if (!hasPermission && this.hasPermissionJustDisable) {
                    this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
                    this.elementRef.nativeElement.nextElementSibling.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
                    return;
                }
                this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
            });
    }
}
```

Problem is, it doesn't disable the button.. But if I removed the `mat-raised-button` like so:

```
            <button  *hasPermission="PERMISSION_TYPES.Admin; justDisable: true" >
                DISABLE USER
            </button>
```

Then the button is disabled.  It must have something to do with how angular material is rendering these.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: I'd have to test to be sure and I don't use material stuff but you're using js vanilla `nextElementSibling` which in this case is looking for a component DOM node so it's gracefully failing. If instead you used [renderer2](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2#nextsibling) which is [the better way anyway](https://medium.com/better-programming/angular-manipulate-properly-the-dom-with-renderer-16a756508cba) than it should work, or just hit the `[disabled]` @Input property directly and accomplish the same thing with a quick bool `<mat-raised-button [disabled]="bool".....`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion on using Renderer. If that's better practice I will use it. But I was able to solve it with wrapping it in a setTimeout.. I will post the answer. I couldn't use the [disabled] directly because it uses an async call.

Comment: Nah man avoid settimeout's for trivial things. At most using `ViewChild` would be the better route but for this case I'd suggest just making it easier on yourself all together but still use the built in angular mechanisms like in this case just putting `[disabled]="!hasPermission && this.hasPermissionJustDisable"` on the button should do it but glad you found a remedy either way.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it by wrapping my setting of disabled in a `SetTimeout` like so:

```
if (!hasPermission && this.hasPermissionJustDisable) {
                    this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
                    // Timeout is required for some rendering quark with angular material buttons..
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        this.renderer.setAttribute(this.elementRef.nativeElement.nextElementSibling, 'disabled', 'disabled');
                    });
                    return;
                }
```